# Hilfe beim verschwommenen Text

Tags: translation

Ein Verwandter von mir hat in unsere Familien-Facebookgruppe folgendes Bild gepostet, dessen Text noch kaum zu erkennen ist. Zumindest für meine Augen.

Link zum Bild:
https://ibb.co/bL0TfKr

Bisher habe ich als Nicht-Deutsch-Muttersprachler die folgenden Wörter erkennen können:

Boj
Melchior boa(?) 1500
Oberschreiber in Schwäbisch Hall

Seit dem ausgehenden XIII Jahrhundert, ab ... (1346 - 1378), haben die Kaiser Wappen verliehen, ohne die Begünstigten in den Adelsstand zu erheben. Im XV Jahrhundert haben sie den  ...grafen(?) mit der Wappen Vergabe betraut, der seitdem Bürgerfamilien Wappen ge... (?).

Ich weiß nicht, ob alles, was ich bisher entziffern konnte, richtig ist. Ich freue mich sehr, wenn ihr mir dabei helfen könntet.

Comment: Besteht keine Möglichkeit, dass dein Verwandter das Bild in höherer Auflösung bereit stellt? Eventuell das Original per E-Mail an dich versendet? Das Bild ist stark komprimiert, ich bezweifle zwar, dass What's app es so stark komprimiert hat, aber eventuell hilft es ja.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich nicht. Der Gruppe bin ich seit kurzem beigetreten und jemand anders hatte schon vor 3 Jahren um ein schärferes Bild gebeten. Ist nie passiert. Ich werde trotzdem nachfragen, trotz gelungener Entzifferung, ob es scharfes Bild existiert. 

Nun sagt der Text nicht wirklich viel aus über den Stamm dieses Nachnamens. Es war nur eine Seite und das war es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Boj
>
> Melchior Boa(?) 1500
>
> Oberschreiber **zu** Schwäbisch Hall
>
> Wappen
>
> Seit dem ausgehenden XIII Jahrhundert, ab **Karl IV.** (1346–1378), haben die Kaiser Wappen verliehen, ohne die Begünstigten in den Adelsstand zu erheben. Im XV Jahrhundert haben sie den **Pfalzgrafen** mit der **Wappenvergabe** betraut, der seitdem Bürgerfamilien Wappen **gewährte**.

Das Schriftzeichen hinter *Boa*, das einem gespiegelten *Epsilon* (*϶*) ähnelt, kann ich nicht erkennen. Plausibel scheint mir ein *s*, doch sehen die anderen *s*-Zeichen in *Oberschreiber* und *Schwäbisch* anders aus.

Comment: Mit Sicherheit "Boas". Siehe [hier](https://forebears.io/de/surnames/boas). "Boas der biblische Boas, der die Ährenleserin Ruth zum Weibe nahm. Melchior Boas 1500 Schwäbisch-Hall."

Answer (score 0):

"Karl IV."; "Pfalzgrafen"; "gewährte."